# Google service account email does not show up when trying to share a google calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to set up a google service account for Google Calendar API to create and update events for my specific calendar.

I've set up my service account, got the credential keys and also enabled the domain wide delegation. For  most of the part it does work, however I can not access my specific calendar (not able to share it with my service account).

When I paste the service account email to the share textbox in google calendar settings it does not show anything to add.

This is a really frustrating blocker, so if anyone has encountered this or has any insights it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "it does not show anything to add." what does this mean?

Comment: I was referring to the field in the Calendar settings -> Share with specific people -> textbox to add a user email.

Comment: Did you copy the service account email address and place it in there?  If your doing domain wide delegation I am not sure why you are sharing it as well though.  Unless this is your personal calendar and not associated with your domain account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You do not need to explicitly share your calendar with the service account.

If you want to create an event with your service account for your calendar, you need to set up your service account in such a way that it impersonates you.

The official Google documentation gives examples of how to perform [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) in different languages. It is also important to do so in [Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script).

> **Important:** In your Admin console you need to `Manage API client access` and give the service account the necessary scope
>   (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events) to create events on
>   your behalf.